# Conversion of design file to shapefile using FME

Tags: microstation, design, fme-form

I want to convert a MicroStation design file to shapefile using FME. I have two type of feature in a level 7. One has style 1 and another one style 3. I want them in different shapefiles.

How can I get FME to differentiate between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fanout shapefile using  igds_linestyle (or igs_linestyle) attribute.
See feature->properties->format attributes->select igds_ atrributes  to expose them.

Comment: well that depends on what you want to do. after you expose igds_* variable/variables it is up to you decide what you need. do you want to concatenate igs_level and linetype to one attribute ehich you use to fanout dataset or use testfilter to direct them to their own writer features